# How to read VCF file in flutter from the server?

Tags: flutter

I have stored some VCF file on the server. I want to read them while fetching.

I searched on Google but didn't find anything related to this.

Comment: What about converting VCF to JSON on server?

Comment: No Idea! Do you have any work around ?